# locating cell containing point in irregular 3D grid

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I have an irregular 3D grid which looks something like this:
[image]  Typical dimensions of the grid are 100/100/100 cells.  Each cell is spatially defined by the coords of the 8 corner nodes. The 4 vertices of the each face of a cell are not necessarily co-planar, so I represent each face as a pair of triangles and thus a cell as a polyhedron consisting of 12 triangles (2 per face). I am trying to locate the IJK index of the cell that contains an XYZ point using Python.  I bisect sequentially the cell range in the I, J and K directions and test which half of the grid the point lies using the method described here [Testing whether a 3D point is inside a 3D polyhedron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513525/testing-whether-a-3d-point-is-inside-a-3d-polyhedron) to locate the point.  Unfortunately, this does not work in some cases.  In the above figure, point A is physically outside the grid but inside the current bisection range (defined by the brown dotted lines) while point B is inside the grid but outside the current range.  I think the reason for this is that triangles representing the faces of the cells within the current range (eg the large brown triangles in the figure) are not co-planar with the triangles that comprise the individual cell faces within that range (eg those shaded yellow, blue etc). I have tried to show this in 2D below:
[image]
The current bisection range is shown by the brown dotted line and brown vertices.  Initially, the red point is within the current range.  We bisect in the X direction (bisection 1) and the red point is within the current range (dotted brown line) so we discard the right half.  We now bisect in the Y direction (bisection 2) and the red point is outisde this range so we discard the top half.  We eventually arrive at the final step when we have a single index in each of the I & J directions.  As shown here, this places the red point in the wrong cell.
Would appreciate any suggestions for an alternative algorithm to the one I am currently trying to implement.  Stepping back, I am actually interested in calculating the faces within the grid intersected by a series of line segments, so am using the "point in a polyhedron" method as an intermediate step.  I looked at `geomdl` which could represent each face as a NURBS object but does not seem to implement intersection between a ray and a NURBS object.  I also had a quick look at the Python bindings to `CGAL` but that looked like a massive learning curve to climb, so put that aside.   Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your description of the lattice is quite obscure. And how can you expect us to make any sense of the "example output" ???

Comment: By lattice I mean a 3D grid, consisting of cells, whose nodes are defined in (X,Y, Z) space and whose cells are indexed by their (I, J, K) location.  The output format is described in the  text but I have added a comment to help explain it better

Comment: You just added titles to the columns, which are of completely no use. Are you serious ?

Comment: Sorry, but you'll have to help me.  What additional explanation do I need to provide?  Line 1 of the results indicates that the point is apparently within the entire grid but line 2 says that it is not in the top half (I=1:68) or the bottom half (I=69:135).say  I have explained that the output shows that the point is inside the

Comment: I can't understand this: "I have a 3D lattice consisting of a collection of boxes, defined by their corner XYZ coordinates, in which the number of cells in each I/J/K slice is the same but the physical shape can vary. The (I,J) coords of a node between adjacent cells are contiguous but the K coord can vary, so that the face of a K layer can contact ... [truncated for brevity] ... of the each face of a given box (cell) are not necessarily co-planar, so I represent each face as a pair of triangles and thus a cell as a polyhedron consisting of 16 triangles."

Comment: OK - understand.  Let me add a picture

Comment: What does the brown triangle represent ?

Comment: Given the quasi-regular structure of the grid, I have the feeling that a hierarchy of axis-aligned bounding boxes with an octonary tree topology will work (the leaves containing a single cell each). At the lowest level of the search, your point can belong to several boxes, and you can't spare a point-in-polyhedron for each grid cell to arbitrate.

Comment: The brown triangle tries to represent one of the triangles that make up the faces of bounding box of the currently "active" bisection region

Comment: I see. Sorry but this triangle is uninformative.